# Python Threading. Why can I only run one thread at a time

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I am experimenting with threading for a project I am working on. Here is the code I am using as a test

```
import threading


class one(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        while 1:
            print "one"


class two(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        while 1:
            print "two"

threads = []

one = one()
two = two()

one.start()
two.start()


threads.append(one)
threads.append(two)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

The problem is that only class one runs. Can you see a problem with my code?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get the idea of overriding `__init__`?

Comment: From this post http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: As it happens I have solved the problem. I did not use the required def run(self): method in each of the classes.

Answer (score 4):

You have to override the `run` method, not `__init__`:

```
class one(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print "one"
```

This method is what is executed on a different thread, while `one = one()` starts an infinite loop in the same thread that the object is created.

Override `__init__` if you want to pass an argument to be used in the new thread, for instance:

```
class NumberedThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, number):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.number = number

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print self.number

NumberedThread("one").start()
NumberedThread("two").start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've put an infinite loop in your thread constructor. Your first "thread" never even gets out of its constructor, so the code that's trying to create it just sits and waits for the object to be created. As a result, you aren't actually multithreading anything: you've just got an infinite loop in the main thread.

Override `run` instead of `__init__` and you should be all set.

```
class one(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print "one"


class two(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print "two"
```